# Is there a typographic mark for a page break?

Tags: text, typography, icon

In the same way MS Word and other word processors use middots for spaces, pilcrows for paragraphs and the little right arrows for tabs, is there a typographic mark to represent the concept of a page break?

Some prior research on my part:

Unicode has "U+240C Symbol For Form Feed" in "Control Pictures", which is the initials of the words Form Feed (␌). In MS-DOS codepage 437, the control code for form feed is the female sign (♀). However, neither of these symbols represent the concept of a page break.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Form Feed is technically a page break. It's an instruction to the printer to eject the current page, and begin printing the next page. There is a printable Unicode symbol which could be used for a Form Feed: U+21A1 ↡ which is a vertical line with two downward facing arrow heads. This character doesn't perform a Form Feed, though.

If you are looking for something a bit more obvious/graphical to represent a page break, there are icons such as those shown on the [Noun Project](https://thenounproject.com/search/icons/?q=page+break).

Some examples from the Noun Project (at the link above)

[image]

Note: I have no affiliation with the Noun Project. There are other similar icon sites such as FlatIcon, Icons8, etc.

Comment: Thanks, U+21A1 was what I was after.